# Mocking TemporaryUploadedFile in Django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, file-upload, mocking

I'm using Django (1.10.5) together with DRF (3.5.4) to create API. I've defined a view to handle file upload and call the `foo` method with the data passed in the post request and the path to temporary file where the uploaded file is being stored.

```
class FooView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = NewFooSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            file_obj = serializer.validated_data["my_file"]
            name = serializer.validated_data["name"]
            foo_id = my_module.foo(name=name, my_file=file_obj.temporary_file_path())
            result_url = reverse('api:foo', kwargs={"foo_id": foo_id})
            return Response({"result_url": result_url}, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

My serializer to validate incoming data looks like this

```
class NewFooSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    my_file = serializers.FileField()
```

Basically I'd like to test this view without the filesystem interaction using `mock` library. My current test method is defined below

```
    @mock.patch('my_module.foo')
    def test_post_should_invoke_foo_method(self, mocked_foo):
        mocked_foo.return_value = "123456"
        self.client.post(self.VIEW_URL,
                         {'my_file': self.file_mock,
                          'name': 'Test file'
                          }, format='multipart')
        mocked_new.assert_called_with(name="Test file", my_file="/some/dummy/path"
```

This one of course raises `AssertionError`

```
AssertionError: Expected call: foo(my_file='/some/dummy/path', name='Test file')
Actual call: foo(my_file='/tmp/tmp0VrYgR.upload', name=u'Test file')
```

I couldn't find any solution how to mock `TemporaryUploadedFile` so I tried to mock `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` which is being used by this class. So I've added these lines before `TestCase`

```
named_temporary_file_mock = mock.MagicMock(spec=tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile)
named_temporary_file_mock.name = mock.MagicMock()
named_temporary_file_mock.name.return_value = "/some/dummy/path"
```

and then decorate my test method with

```
@mock.patch('tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile', named_temporary_file_mock)
```

But unfortunately this results in the same error as previous version. What I might be missing? Should I take another approach to avoid interaction with the filesystem?